# Receiver on tokio's mpsc channel only receives messages when buffer is full

Tags: rust, rust-tokio, channel

I've spent a few hours trying to figure this out and I'm pretty done. I found the question with a similar name, but that looks like something was blocking synchronously which was messing with tokio. That very well may be the issue here, but I have absolutely no idea what is causing it.

Here is a heavily stripped down version of my project which hopefully gets the issue across.

```
use std::io;
use futures_util::{
    SinkExt,
    stream::{SplitSink, SplitStream},
    StreamExt,
};
use tokio::{
    net::TcpStream,
    sync::mpsc::{channel, Receiver, Sender},
};
use tokio_tungstenite::{
    connect_async,
    MaybeTlsStream,
    tungstenite::Message,
    WebSocketStream,
};

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    connect_to_server("wss://a_valid_domain.com".to_string()).await;
}

async fn read_line() -> String {
    loop {
        let mut str = String::new();
        io::stdin().read_line(&mut str).unwrap();

        str = str.trim().to_string();
        if !str.is_empty() {
            return str;
        }
    }
}

async fn connect_to_server(url: String) {
    let (ws_stream, _) = connect_async(url).await.unwrap();

    let (write, read) = ws_stream.split();
    let (tx, rx) = channel::<ChannelMessage>(100);

    tokio::spawn(channel_thread(write, rx));
    tokio::spawn(handle_std_input(tx.clone()));

    read_messages(read, tx).await;
}

#[derive(Debug)]
enum ChannelMessage {
    Text(String),
    Close,
}


// PROBLEMATIC FUNCTION
async fn channel_thread(
    mut write: SplitSink<WebSocketStream<MaybeTlsStream<TcpStream>>, Message>,
    mut rx: Receiver<ChannelMessage>,
) {
    while let Some(msg) = rx.recv().await {
        println!("{:?}", msg); // This only fires when buffer is full
        match msg {
            ChannelMessage::Text(text) => write.send(Message::Text(text)).await.unwrap(),
            ChannelMessage::Close => {
                write.close().await.unwrap();
                rx.close();

                return;
            }
        }
    }
}

async fn read_messages(
    mut read: SplitStream<WebSocketStream<MaybeTlsStream<TcpStream>>>,
    tx: Sender<ChannelMessage>,
) {
    while let Some(msg) = read.next().await {
        let msg = match msg {
            Ok(m) => m,
            Err(_) => continue
        };

        match msg {
            Message::Text(m) => println!("{}", m),
            Message::Close(_) => break,
            _ => {}
        }
    }

    if !tx.is_closed() {
        let _ = tx.send(ChannelMessage::Close).await;
    }
}

async fn handle_std_input(tx: Sender<ChannelMessage>) {
    loop {
        let str = read_line().await;
        if tx.is_closed() {
            break;
        }

        tx.send(ChannelMessage::Text(str)).await.unwrap();
    }
}
```

As you can see, what I'm trying to do is:

- Connect to a websocket
- Print outgoing messages from the websocket
- Forward any input from stdin to the websocket
- Also a custom heartbeat solution which was trimmed out

The issue lies in the channel_thread() function. I move the websocket writer into this function as well as the channel receiver. The issue is, it only loops over the sent objects when the buffer is full.

I've spent a lot of time trying to solve this, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Looks like `read_messages` never actually sends anything to the `tx` (except the final "close" method), is this intentional?

Comment: @Coder-256 Yeah it is intentional- I have a few other threads that also send to tx, like a heartbeat as mentioned.

Comment: Weird. Maybe try only spawning a thread that sends a message to the mpsc every 30 ms and yields between each message for good measure, then see if it's really true that it only fires when the buffer is full. Sometimes things like this can just come down to the order that lines appear in stdout when you are running things quickly in parallel.

Comment: @Coder-256 Thanks for the advice! I did some testing earlier where I literally just typed 100 messages and they ALL got sent to the websocket at once. Also tried it with the buffer set to a size of 1. Same result. The entire time the websocket was fine printing any messages from the websocket.

Comment: `io::stdin().read_line(...)` is synchronous. You are calling a sync function in an async context, which can block that entire thread for other async tasks. You never _ever_ make blocking synchronous calls from an async function.

Comment: @cdhowie Ah- that would make sense. Didn't even realize. Thanks so much!

Comment: @Cooper No problem. I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here, you make a blocking synchronous call in an async context:

```
async fn read_line() -> String {
    loop {
        let mut str = String::new();
        io::stdin().read_line(&mut str).unwrap();
        //          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        //          This is sync+blocking

        str = str.trim().to_string();
        if !str.is_empty() {
            return str;
        }
    }
}
```

You never **ever** make blocking synchronous calls in an async context, because that prevents the entire thread from running other async tasks.  Your channel receiver task is likely also assigned to this thread, so it's having to wait until all the blocking calls are done and whatever invokes this function yields back to the async runtime.

Tokio has [its own async version of `stdin`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/io/fn.stdin.html), which you should use instead.

Answer (score 1):

I initially came here for a separate issue, but I wanted to share some of my findings with you.

If you're sending messages in a tight loop without yielding back to the Tokio scheduler, the sender may monopolize the thread and prevent the receiver task from being scheduled to process messages. This can create the appearance that messages are only received when the buffer is full, particularly if the buffer size is small.

Using [tokio::task::yield_now](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/task/fn.yield_now.html) can resolve this issue.

Comment: This is true not just for sending, but for all CPU-intensive works which don't yield. Also, you probably want to use bounded channels anyway if you send all the time, to avoid an OOM.

Comment: Yes, the statement can be applied to a broader context.